# App Navigation state persisting EVEN IF app closed and restarted

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a react-native app with two screens, Home and Details. Using react-navigation, Ive set the Stack navigator as following

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
{
 Home: FormComponent,
 Details: DetailScreen
},
{
 initialRouteName: "Home",
 headerMode: "none"
}
);
```

Home contains a form, which once submitted, navigates to the Details screen with relevant data (using navigation.navigate("Details",{some data})). At this point, if I exit the app, and then open it again, the Details screen loads, with all the data preserved(Instead of the Home screen). I logged the navigation object data (this.props.navigation.) and it prints like the app was never closed.
Am I missing something here? Im new to React Native and Navigation, but from what I understand this is not expected behaviour.

Tried uninstalling app and rebuilding. This resets the app and Home screen loads. If I try reinstalling without uninstalling, back to same behaviour.
Tried also manually forcing navigation.goBack() on ComponentWillUnmount() but no difference.

Comment: You definitely closed it (with a swipe?). Otherwise it still has an AppState of background.

Comment: If you are on Android, there is really no "exit" that you are in control of. I don't know how React works with Android, but generally you need to think about the app lifecycle, and understand that the lifecycle is driven by the platform, not the application. Make sure you know that how React works here actually results in a lifecycle change that you understand.

Comment: @stever It was to do with react navigation storing the state in the persistence key property. Removing it solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should've been a comment but sadly i don't have enough reputation.
Could you check if you haven't accidentally set a persistenceKey as a navigator prop?

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/state-persistence.html

Comment: Well, Im ashamed to say, i missed it. Added it much earlier and then sort of forgot about it. You were right. Removed it and works fine. 
Probably why I added it was because I was trying to retain state when you switch apps but hit the notification that the app generates to return to the app